# Importing sql data from AWS RDS service to AWS elasticsearch managed service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, import

Have been playing aroung with this issue for sometime and unable to get the right way to solve the subject.I used jdbc importer but for that i had to setup ec2 instance which could be more dirty when it gets to managing and scaling .

Any help will be highly appreciated.